# Individual column filtering in header. How to change the width of search filter textbox for each column's individually?

Tags: javascript, datatable

On my JavaScript code one style width value is set for all search-textboxes, and I can't resize them one by one.

```
$('#detailed thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#detailed thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="popoverData" data-content="Please enter a '+title+'" rel="popover"' +
        ' data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" style="width:80;" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
```

Comment: Please can you format your code into something a little more readable? - Also, what is your expected outcome? What isn't working? Do you have any console errors? - Please update your question.

Comment: It's edited now, please see the full code.
I need to resize the search-boxes from my table one by one, not all at once like here  style="width:80;"
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the individual `<input>`'s by simple CSS :

```css
#detailed thead th:nth-child(1) input {
  width: 30px !important;
  max-width: 30px !important;
}

#detailed thead th:nth-child(3) input {
  width: 80px !important;
  max-width: 80px !important;
}
```

and so on. If you discover problems (which I do not expect) set `autoWidth: false`.

Comment: Can you please show me how to display multiline text on this <input> ?

Comment: @ciprigothic, why dont you use a `<textarea>`? It is the only form element that (officially) support multiiple lines.  You can disable the resize functionality by `textarea { resize: none; }` so it appears as a text `<input>`.

Comment: but how can I use this between `<th></th>` in order to display multiiple lines on the header of column.
not works with:  

`<th><textarea name="textarea" rows="3" cols="10">Write something here</textarea></th>`

Comment: I guess "not works" mean that you have forgotten to change the event `$( 'textarea', this.header() )` ...?

Comment: can you please show me how to implement/change this event?

Comment: Hey @ciprigothic, ?? In your code you have `$( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {` change `input` to `textarea`, this is what you need if you now are inserting textareas instead of inputs.